# powershell - gci exclude directories and subdirectories where parent folder contains TECH?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

having trouble excluding directories and all subdirectories under excluded parent.
i run this but need to exclude directory and subdirectories that start with TECH or have it in path.

```
 c:\users\user1
         user2
         tech-xxx  (random numbers - need to exclude this and all subdirectories)
         tech-xxx  (random numbers - need to exclude this and all subdirectories)
```

These fail (along with many other variations i have tried):

```
$UserDirExtensions="*.cmd","*.bat"
gci C:\Users -Recurse -Include $UserDirExtensions | Where-Object {!($_.FullName -icontains 'tech*')
```

---

```
$Folders = (gci C:\Users -Directory | Select-Object -Property name | Where {$_.Name -notlike 'tech*' })
foreach ($i in $Folders) {
    gci C:\Users\$i -Recurse -Include $UserDirExtensions
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try this : `Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch 'tech')`

Answer (score 3):

name isn't fullname. -contains doesn't do what you think, it matches whole words in an array basically, and doesn't use wildcards.

```
dir -r | where fullname -notlike *tech*
```

There's a couple ways to focus on the parent, but this wouldn't exclude a tech folder itself:

```
dir -r | where psparentpath -notlike *tech*
dir -r | where directory -notlike *tech*
dir -r | where directoryname -notlike *tech*
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the full cmdlet names along with the full parameter names. This would make your code much easier to read and easier to understand even for beginners.